# For x in range, trying to input data, index [0] and [-1] need no data input

Tags: python, input, indexing, types, range

Language is python3, and i'm just a beginner. I need a loop, where it is looped "number" amount of times, collecting input data from the user. "Number" is a input by the user, which was collected before. For the first loop, since its logically not correct to gather data for one of the input(questions), i only want the other question asked and the logically incorrect question to return a value of 0. And vice versa for the last loop. All loops in the in between the first and last loop need to ask both questions to gather data.

```
for x in range(Number):



        if range([0])):
                value1 = input("question 1")
                value2 = 0
        elif range([-1])):
                value2 = input("question 2")
                value1 = 0

        else:
                value1 = input("question 1")
                value2 = input("question 2")
```

I'm getting a lot of type errors.

Comment: Please add the code for the variable declarations, what language are we talking about and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `if range([0])):` doesn't make much sense (and is syntactially incorrect): what do you want those if-statements to do?

Comment: If you're getting errors that you want to fix, please show the errors

Answer (score 0):

The loop:

```
for x in range(Number):
    print(x)
```

is going to set x to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., Number - 1 for each loop iteration.  You can see this by adding the print statement inside the loop.

If you want to do something the first or last time through the loop, your conditions need to compare to the current value of x:

```
if x == 0:  # first loop iteration
    ...
elif x == Number - 1:  # last loop iteration
    ...
else:  # every other loop iteration
    ...
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `range` function in the conditional statement.